# What is include header for htonl like functions in winsock kernel WSK?

Tags: winsock2, windows-kernel

I'm fairly experienced with WinSock however this is my first venture into Winsock Kernel.  The conversion functions ntohl, htonl ntohs and htons are coming up undefined when I include only < wsk.h >.  What #include should I be using for these conversion functions.  I've done searches for "wsk htonl" without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

RtlUlongByteSwap() should be used in kernel mode instead of ntohl or htonl